# reopen modal dialog jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi
I have a modal dialog what open when the document is ready.
When I close it, I have this error `Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'` at `$("#dialog").dialog('close');` and I can't reopen it.

```
$("#info").find(".openImg").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").load("/Ajax.htm", function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("destroy");
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen : false,
            modal: true,
            height : 300,
            width : 300,
            title : "Title", 
            close : function(event, ui) { $("#dialog").dialog('close'); }
        });
        $("#dialog").prepend("<p>Some text</p>");
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }); 
});
```

What the solution?

Answer (score 2):

i dont think you need to be calling close in the close callback of the dialog.

the close callback is for doing stuff when the dialog is closed. what you are doing is probably creating an inf recursion by calling close in the close callback.

Comment: If I don't do the close I still have an error at the next call of dialog

Comment: does ajax.html contain any scripts? it may be possible that you are overwriting jquery ui or breaking it post load with scripts

Comment: Fine my error, ajax.html contains jquery too and that create the problem so I revomed it. Thanks.